# Matlab: how to save animated plot to a gif

Tags: matlab, gif

Consider the following function that draws an animated plot of cicloid.

```
function animate1()
    clear, clc

    R = 1; 
    na = -pi/2; 
    t = 0:0.05:6;
    v = 4; 

    for i = 1:length(t)
        x0 = v*t(i); 
        y0 = R;
        na = -v*t(i)/R; 
        fi = linspace(na,na+2*pi,100); 
        x = x0 + R*cos(fi); 
        y = y0 + R*sin(fi);

        xc(i) = x0 + R*cos(na);
        yc(i) = y0 + R*sin(na);

        plot(x,y,'b',... 
            xc(i),yc(i),'*m',... 
            xc,yc,'r') 
        axis([-1 25 0 1.5])
        axis equal
        pause(0.01)
    end
```

Is it possible to modify the code in such a way that it output animated plot e.g. to a gif?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `imwrite` does support animated GIFs. Like for AVI videos, you grab frames via `getframe` sequentially. Then pass them to `imwrite` though for GIFs you have to convert them from RGB to a 256 colormap before. Like this:

```
for i = 1:nFrames

    % draw stuff

    frame = getframe(gcf);
    img =  frame2im(frame);
    [img,cmap] = rgb2ind(img,256);
    if i == 1
        imwrite(img,cmap,'animation.gif','gif','LoopCount',Inf,'DelayTime',1);
    else
        imwrite(img,cmap,'animation.gif','gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',1);
    end
end
```

Have a look at `openExample('matlab/WriteAnimatedGIFExample')` and at `doc imwrite` for more information.

Comment: but what is `gcf` in `frame = getframe(gcf);` ?

Comment: @Eugeny89 `gcf` returns the current figure handle. Have a look at the [documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

Comment: Exactly, thanks @Cebri, `gcf` is short for get current figure. Therefore, `getframe(gcf)` will grab the whole current figure. You can also use `getframe(gca)` (`gca` = get current axis) if you only want to grab the current axis (i.e., without legends, tick markers, etc.).